# swift 2.1 use of unresolved identifier

Tags: sql, database, xcode, swift, singleton

I am developing an app which uses a sqlite database..
So I wrote this Singleton class as a model manager :

```
class ModelManager {
    static let sharedInstance = ModelManager()
    var database = FMDatabase(path: Utility.getPath("myDB.sqlite"))


    class func getInstance() -> ModelManager {
        if(sharedInstance.database == nil) {
            sharedInstance.database = FMDatabase(path: Utility.getPath("myDB.sqlite"))
        }

        return sharedInstance
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get compiler error when I use the `sharedInstance` that says `use of unresolved identifier sharedInstance`

For example in this class where I add data to the database

```
func addSData(favBuddy: favorites) -> Bool {
    sharedInstance.database!.open()
    let isInserted = sharedInstance.database!.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO favorties (eName, eEmail) VALUES (test, test)", withArgumentsInArray: [favorties.eName, favorties.eMail])
    sharedInstance.database!.close()
    return isInserted
}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: It's `sharedInstance`, not `sharedInstanc` ...

Comment: It is a mistyping, the post is edited with the other class code now

Comment: It always helps to copy/paste the *exact* error messages ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm inferring from your question that you are trying to access your shared database instance from a separate class. In that case, you need to do: `ModelManager.sharedInstance`